# Using JaCoCo to generate coverage reports for a website and code executed as part of POST, GET, etc. isn't tracked

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

Using Java, Maven and JaCoCo to run Integration/Unit tests.  The only valid way to test our website is to call URL's and have it trigger the undrelying code.  Unfortunately, JaCoCo is only logging the "test" code itself, and not the code that is triggered as part of the URL POST, PUT, GET etc.

How can I get it to generate an accurate code coverage report?  Calling the Java Classes directly really doesn't make sense.

Added the plugin and ran tests.

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-reports</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
type here
```